# Efficient way to get max key value from Dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

This is the syntax of my dictionary object

```
Dictionary<int, string> kayAndVal= new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

The problem is that i want to get the max key value available in dictionary variable. I searched all over and found LINQ solutions but i can't use LINQ as my application is in .Net framework 2.o.

This dictionary variable can contain 150 - 200 values. Can someone tell me the efficient way to get it done ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upgrading to a higher framework is not an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to do it the old-fashioned way:

```
int max = int.MinValue;

foreach (int i in dict.Keys)
    max = Math.Max(max, i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could switch to SortedDictionary where you will have a sorted list with keys where the max you want will always be the last (or first, not sure if it's ascending/descending) value in the keys list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library which backports parts of LINQ to .NET 2.0: [LINQBridge](https://code.google.com/p/linqbridge)